# Using Google OR-Tools, CP-SAT, how do you make an assignment to a BoolVar?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

```
BoolVar x = model.NewBoolVar("");
model.Add(x == 0);
```

This is the only way I can determine how to create a simple assignment to a BoolVar. It's suboptimal, though, as Add creates a linear constraint, rather than a Boolean assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.AddBoolAnd(x)
```

Note that the linear is just temporary. It will be presolved away.

In C++, you also have `model.FixVariable(x, 0);`

Comment: 'And' with a single variable. OMG that's hilarious. Thank you Laurent. I have successfully used CP Sat to build our work schedule for the next quarter. Everyone was ecstatic at how easy it was to add additional scheduling requests and refactor. We will be using it for the foreseeable future. Thanks to the whole team responsible for this.

Comment: yes, but you can fix a whole bunch of them in a single call :-)